# Accessing swift dictionary members using AnyObject

Tags: swift, dictionary, syntax

I'm having trouble with understanding how to properly do unwrapping in Swift. Here is the situation:

I have these two classes:

```
class Alpha
{
  var val: Int

  init(x: Int)
  {
    val = x
  } 

  func doSomething() -> Int
  {
    // does stuff and returns an Int value
    return val
  }
}
```

and a second class which is a subclass of the first

```
class Beta: Alpha
{
  var str: [String] = []

  override init(x: Int)
  {
    super.init(x)
  }

  func doSomething() -> String
  {
    // does stuff and returns a String
    return str
  }
}
```

So far so good, these two classes work as expected. But now I want to create a dictionary to store several of both these class objects. So I've created a class to manage the dictionary and add items to it.

```
class Gamma
{
  var myDict: [String:AnyObject] = [:]

  func addAlphaToDict(key: String, val: Int)
  {
    self.myDict[key] = Alpha(x: val).self
  }

  func addBetaToDict(key: String, val: Int)
  {
    self.myDict[key] = Beta(x: val).self
  }
}
```

This also is working, but I think this could somehow be improved. The issue I'm having is now when I try to access values in the dictionary:

```
var foo = Gamma()

foo.addAlphaToDict(key: "blah", val: 45)
foo.addBetaToDict(key: "bluh", val: 23)

var result1 = (foo.myDict["blah"] as! Alpha).doSomething()

var result2 = (foo.myDict["bluh"] as! Beta).doSomething()
```

I find that the syntax here is very clunky and I feel like I'm doing it wrong, even though it works. I'm an experienced developer, but have only just started using Swift so I'm not really sure about certain things. Could someone with more Swift experience show me how to improve this code, or point me in the direction I should be going? Thanks!

Comment: *"even though it works"* – Your code does not compile in my Xcode 10.1

Comment: I don't know what to say to you, it's working fine for me. I'm printing out the results to the console and they're behaving as expected. Can you tell me what error you're getting?

Comment: "Property 'self.str' not initialized at super.init call” in the B.init method, “Ambiguous use of 'doSomething()'” at the `var result2 = ... as! Beta).doSomething()` line. “Missing return” in both `doSomething` functions.

Comment: `var str: String = []` – Please post (copy/paste) your *real* code.

Comment: The code is proprietary and classified, I can't post the exact code in a public forum so I'm doing the best I can.

Comment: Then start a *new* project, copy everything into it that is needed to reproduce the problem. Check that it compiles and runs as you claim before posting. In other words, a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In swift when you want a heterogeneous type with a finite number of possibilities, prefer an `enum` with associated values to `Any` or `AnyObject`.  You can then use a `switch` to recover the type in an exhaustive and type safe way.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

enum DictionaryValues {
    case integer(Int), string(String)
}

let dictionary: [String: DictionaryValues] = ["a": .integer(1), "b": .string("xyz")]

for (key, value) in dictionary {
    switch value {
    case .integer(let number):
        print("Key \(key) is a number: \(number)")
    case .string(let text):
        print("Key \(key) is text: \(text)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the sort of thing I was looking for. I knew my code was super clunky and there surely had to be a better way. This is a much more elegant way of accomplishing what I'm doing. I'm going to try it out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Alpha` instead of `AnyObject` as your dictionary value in this case. Just downcast it to `Beta` when needed. Using `AnyObject` or `Any` as the dictionary key should be avoided as much as possible.

However, i have to say that this approach is bad. You need to have a clearer logic to decide when the key will be `Beta` other than just relaying on knowing which key you are passing to the dictionary.

Comment: how do I downcast to Beta? I tried to do something like that already and I couldn't figure it out? Also, yes I agree that this approach is ambigious like you say, but it doesn't particularly matter in case as the results are all just going to be displayed, and not used for any further computations.

Comment: @fiend i suggest you post the code exactly as it is so that people can actually run it without compilation errors and post solutions.